# FPDF in CodeIgniter show only a blank sheet

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I have two features which uses FPDF in the application I am developing. The other one prints things correctly, while the other outputs only a blank sheet and I really dont know where's the error in here. I already tried to var_dump to know if values are fetch correctly from the database and everything is good except for this printing the pdf part. What should I do? 
Here is the code snippet for the one that only outputs a blank sheet.

```
function generate(){
    $sample= $this->model_a->get_a();
    $j = 10;
    $pdf = new FPDF();                                  
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetMargins(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    $pdf->Cell(40,4,'TITLE','',0,'C',0); 
    $pdf->setXY(12.5,$j+=4);

    $pdf->SetFont('times','B',10);
    $pdf->Cell(42,4,'COL1','TLRB',0,'C',0); 
    $pdf->Cell(100,4,'NAME','TLRB',0,'C',0); 
    $pdf->Cell(42,4,'NAME2','TLRB',0,'C',0);

    foreach($sample as $s){
        $x= $s['id'];
        $y= "{$s['f_name']}, {$s['l_name']} {$s['mi']}.";
        $z= "{$s['f_name1']}, {$s['l_name1']} {$student['mi1']}.";
        $this->addRow($pdf,$x,$y,$z, $j);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
}

function addRow($pdf,$x,$y,$z,&$j){
    $pdf->setXY(12.5,$j+=4);
    $pdf->SetFont('times','',10);
    $pdf->Cell(42,4,$x,'TLRB',0,'C',0); 
    $pdf->Cell(100,4,$y,'TLRB',0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(42,4,$z,'TLRB',0,'C',0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the function addRow have to return the pdf object. Alternatively you can create the new FPDF in a variable class ($this->pdf) and change all the other $pdf.